# I don't understand the value that "push" returns

Tags: arrays, perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub maximum_value {

    my @array  = @_;
    my @array1 = shift( @_ );
    my @array2 = push( @_, 0 );

    print "@array\n";
    print "@array1\n";
    print "@array2\n";

    my $i = 0;

    foreach ( @array ) {

        if ( $i < $_ ) {
            $i = $_;
        }
    }

    print "\nMax Value is $i";
}

maximum_value( 10, 15, 11, 13 );
```

This is a Perl script. I am passing the values to a subroutine and storing them in `@_` . Why does `@array2` evaluate to 4?

Comment: You already got a great answer but may I ask what you expected to be in `@array2`?

Answer (score 8):

[`perldoc -f push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) states:

> Returns the number of elements in the array following the completed push.

1. Your `@_` starts with four elements because you invoked your sub with 4 arguments.
2. You `shift` the first element from the `@_` array. The `shift` returns the removed element. The `@_` array now contains 3 elements.
3. You `push` the zero onto the end of the `@_` array, which contains 4 elements again. The `push` returns the number of elements, and assigns it to `@array2`.